# Using dbus-send to address 127.0.0.1 for a custom method

Tags: linux, dbus

I'm trying to get `dbus-send --address` to work on address 127.0.0.1 port 10010 for a custom method (`com.example.Test.TestMethod`) I have written for myself.  By itself it isn't a useful thing to do, but I'm trying to accomplish something more and this is a test step.

---

First, I've convinced myself my test method works like it should.  Using the system bus locally succeeds for my method:

```
$ dbus-send --system --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.example.Test /com/example/Test com.example.Test.TestMethod string:foo
method return sender=:1.0 -> dest=:1.17 reply_serial=2
   string "returning foo"
```

---

Second, using `--address` fails (I don't understand why it fails):

```
$ dbus-send --address=tcp:host=127.0.0.1,port=10010 --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.example.Test /com/example/Test com.example.Test.TestMethod string:foo
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

`dbus-monitor` shows absolutely nothing:

```
$ DBUS_VERBOSE=1 dbus-monitor --system
(nothing)
```

---

Third, using `--address` on `org.freedesktop.DBus.Hello` succeeds.  I don't know why this succeeds, while my method fails:

```
$ dbus-send --address=tcp:host=127.0.0.1,port=10010 --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.Hello
method return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=:1.15 reply_serial=1
   string ":1.15"
```

---

I have made some modifications to the configuration file `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf`:

```
  <auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>
  <allow_anonymous/>

<listen>tcp:host=127.0.0.1,port=10010</listen>

    <allow send_destination="com.example.Test"/>
    <allow own="com.example.Test"/>
```

---

For debugging, I've used `DBUS_VERBOSE=1` on `dbus-send`, but I don't see anything of use in the output.  The failure case and success case have minimally differing output:

Successful case (`org.freedesktop.DBus.Hello`):

```
[dbus/dbus-transport-socket.c(879):do_reading]  read 89 bytes
[dbus/dbus-marshal-header.c(745):_dbus_header_have_message_untrusted] have 89 bytes, need body 9 + header 80 = 89
[dbus/dbus-marshal-validate.c(723):_dbus_validate_body_with_reason] validating body from pos 0 len 89 sig 'yyyyuua(yv)'
```

Failing case (`com.example.Test.TestMethod`):

```
[dbus/dbus-transport-socket.c(873):do_reading] Disconnected from remote app
[dbus/dbus-transport.c(502):_dbus_transport_disconnect] start
[dbus/dbus-transport-socket.c(1017):socket_disconnect] 
[dbus/dbus-transport-socket.c(76):free_watches] start
[dbus/dbus-watch.c(628):dbus_watch_set_data] Setting watch fd -1 data to data = (nil) function = (nil) from data = (nil) function = (nil)
[dbus/dbus-watch.c(628):dbus_watch_set_data] Setting watch fd -1 data to data = (nil) function = (nil) from data = (nil) function = (nil)
[dbus/dbus-transport-socket.c(98):free_watches] end
[dbus/dbus-transport.c(513):_dbus_transport_disconnect] end
```

---

I've also started the debug mode `dbus-daemon` with `DBUS_VERBOSE=1`, but I can't find the output anywhere.  It's not in syslog.  It's possible that I don't have the debug version, but I find that unlikely as `dbus-send` and `dbus-monitor` are apparently debug variants.

---

I've tried the same experiments on the session bus, with the same results.

---

Version info:

```
$ dbus-daemon --version
D-Bus Message Bus Daemon 1.6.8

$ cat /etc/debian_version
7.6
```

My ultimate goal is to use D-bus for passing messages between computers.    Getting `dbus-send --address` to work for the local case is just my first step on the way.

---

Update Oct. 16 2014: I was able to get this to work.  The solution is counter-intuitive.

There are two requirements.

You have to communicate using use the **SYSTEM** bus.
You have to set the **SESSION** bus address environment variable.

```
$ DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=192.168.56.101,port=10010 dbus-send --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=com.example.Test /com/example/Test com.example.Test.TestMethod string:foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because dbus daemon asks for [local secret](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#auth-mechanisms-sha) and your client does not know how to read it. Can you try to dump entire handshake with wireshirk? (alternatively, you can use my [dbus-dissect](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/blob/master/bin/dbus-dissect.js) script, but it might need some source code tweaks)